# Custom Taxonomy Images with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: custom-taxonomy, images, advanced-custom-fields

I've created a custom Taxonomy for a Custom Post Type, and created five or so terms within the taxonomy.

I've created a single image upload and assigned it to the custom taxonomy, and uploaded images for each term.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the image to display. I've var_dumped the term but there's nothing in there about the image?

Any help much appreciated!

WP version: 3.4.2
ACF version: 3.5.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the plugin [documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/tutorials/retrieving-values-from-other-pages-taxonomy-user-media/):

> The second parameter needed is a string in the format “$type_$id”.

```
// get value from a taxonomy (taxonomy = "category", id = 3)
$value = get_field('field_name', 'category_3');

// get value from a taxonomy (taxonomy = "events", id = 76)
$value = get_field('field_name', 'events_76');
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as brasofilo said but if you may need to generate the taxonomy name and ID and in that instance the following code will help:

```
$taxonomy = $category->taxonomy;
$term_id = $category->term_id; 

$image =  wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('thumbnail', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id), 'shop_catalog');

if ( $image )
  echo '<img src="' . $image[0] . '" alt="" />';
```

This is for an example of a custom query ($category) and for an Image ID. Hope that helps expand upon the other question.

Answer (score 0):

The code of raison's answer didn't worked for me...

My code to get taxonomy name and term id in automatic way is like that:

```
$taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );
$taxonomy_name = $taxonomy->name;
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$image_ids = get_field('your acf field name here', $taxonomy_name . '_' . $term_id , false or true or empty or string inside '' -  Depending on your field type);
```