# How to Retrieve All Category Images on Front-End

Tags: php, categories

I am trying to retrieve all the images from every category. `wp_list_categories` gives me all the titles of categories but I need only the images of category and the permalinks of the individual categories.

I found a helpful topic [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135208/display-image-for-a-category-using-get-categories-or-show-an-image-from-any-chi) but not similar to mine. I also have searched WordPress documentation but can't figure it out how to achieve my goal. Any kind of hints will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a featured image plugin installed on your site for categories? Out of the box a category does not have an image, can you elaborate further on what you mean by a "category image"? It's not clear. Keep in mind that WP functions are building blocks, sometimes you have to use a handful to build you want out of simpler parts, there isn't a handy function for everything

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added a custom field using ACF plugin for categories and it gives get_field() option to retrieve anything. I also added images to all categories.

Comment: Ah so all categories have a custom field containing an image? Is this an image field, or is it a content field that might contain an image? What is its name? These are all super important details that should have been in your question, we don't know how you set up your site, especially when it comes to ACF

Comment: Yeah all categories have a custom field containing image. This is an image field.Its field name 'image'. Thank you so much for your continuous help.

Comment: And for this moment I am working on local dev environment, no npm, gulp installed, just simple wordpress installation and writing code, this is the only one plugin I used.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is too complex, you need to break it apart into multiple, simpler problems. If we don't do this, the problem is much harder, and searching online for somebody who had exactly the same set of problems is much more difficult if not impossible.

So lets do this with pseudocode, code written in plain english as you would tell a lamens:

```
categories = get all categories
for each category in "categories"
    image ID = get the image ID from the image field
    image URL = get the URL for the attachment with the ID of "image ID"
    display the image
    display the title of the category
```

Now we have several smaller, more manageable problems, each of which can be independently researched, with a significantly higher number of solutions and resources:

- how do I get all categories?
- how do I get an image out of an ACF Field on a category
  = given an image ID, how do I get a URL

It might be that these questions too need breaking down into smaller easier problems as we do research to figure out how to do it.

Note that all of these are very good questions to ask here, you could have gotten 3x the reputation, and, gotten longer more in depth answers for each part.

So we can take the pseudocode and start swapping out the plain english for real PHP code:

```
$categories = [];// get all categories
foreach ( category in "categories" ) {
    //image ID = get the image ID from the image field
    //image URL = get the URL for the attachment with the ID of "image ID"
    //display the image
    //display the title of the category
}
```

Beginning with how do we fill `categories` with all the categories? I believe you have already found the answer to the first one, but it's hidden in a more complex question. The `get_categories` function is what you want.

Next "how do I get an image out of an ACF Field on a category", would lead you to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73803/custom-taxonomy-images-with-advanced-custom-fields)

And finally "given an image ID, how do I get a URL", to do this you would use `wp_get_attachment_url`, [which is documented with examples here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url)

As a final note, you never want to show all the posts, or all the categories. This is because as the number of categories grows, so does the time to generate the page and run the queries. Eventually so many are present that the page never finishes loading or the DB struggles under load, putting an upper limit on how many people can view your site at the same time, if they can view it at all. Instead, put an upper limit of 200 categories so this is never an issue